# xcode+picker in horizontal form

Tags: xcode

I want to develop an application where I want to make the picker in horizontal way. Or the set of adjust the array in such way.

As shown in the image below:

[image]

Please guide me how can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can rotate the UIPicker

The transform code:

```
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);
    rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 0.1, 0.8);
    [self.pickerView setTransform:rotate];
```

Comment: thanks i got the solution.  http://isujith.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/horizontal-uipickerview/